# How to Detect Requests Package in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-requests, atom-editor

I know this is ridiculous, but I'm getting "no module named requests" errors, when I thought I was installing the requests package to the right directory in my virtual environment.

I create a virtual environment with the --no-site-packages flag, then activate said virtual environment, then pip install requests with no errors, then I receive errors in Atom saying there is no module named requests. The file I am getting the error on is in the virtual environment directory that I just created. Should the file be in the bin or lib folders?

Comment: Does Atom look the right directory(which is your virtualenv) for python interpreter?

Comment: That's probably the problem, let me see if I can figure it out myself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @metmirr so you're right, when I run my program in my virtualenv via the command line, the python interpreter does detect requests, however when I try and run the program in atom via the script package requests is not detected.

Comment: I ended up figuring this out, I needed to launch atom from the same directory my virtual environment is in. Had the same problem with BeautifulSoup.